# Running wrapper file continuously for using JFR to monitor ActiveMQ performance

Tags: activemq-classic, wrapper, jfr

I have an issue about continuously running **Java Flight Recorder** to monitor memory usage and other performance statistics of **ActiveMQ**.

- Wrapper configuration file (**wrapper.conf**) is under this directory with nearside (**wrapper**, activemq, libwrapper.so) files;

  ../apache-activemq-5.12.1/bin/linux-x86-64/wrapper.conf
- I added the lines below to run JFR;

  ```
   wrapper.java.additional.13=-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures                                            
   wrapper.java.additional.14=-XX:+FlightRecorder
   wrapper.java.additional.15=-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,repository=../jfr/jfrs_%WRAPPER_PID%,settings=profile
   wrapper.java.additional.16=-XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=../jfr/jfrs_%WRAPPER_PID%/myrecording.jfr,dumponexit=true,compress=true
  ```
- When I run **wrapper file**, expected output 'myrecording.jfr' is generated under specified path in wrapper.conf. But the problem is, I also want it to be happen automatically (without running wrapper file by hand).

What might be the possible solution for that?

Comment: I don't know about ActiveMQ, but the command line parameters you use will start two recordings. If you are using a JDK prior to JDK 8u40, remove -XX:StartFlightRecording. If you are using later versions, I would use 
-XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=profile,dumponexit=true,filename=... and remove -XX:+FlightRecorder and only use -XX:FlightRecorderOption for setting the repository location.

Comment: Unfortunately,it didn't work either.